# Autocorrelation function of MA(1)

Tags: economics

I'm very new to this subject. My teacher is following *Walter Enders Applied Econometric Time Series*, and Autocorrelation functions is something I have to know. However I can´t understand this step made in the book. Thanks in advance.

> Considering the process $MA(1)$:  $y_t=\varepsilon_t+\beta\varepsilon_{t-1}$, we can obtain the Yule–Walker equations by multiplying $y_t$ by each $y_{t-s}$ >and take expectations.
>
> $\gamma_0=Ey_ty_t=E[(\varepsilon_t+\beta\varepsilon_{t-1})(\varepsilon_t+\beta\varepsilon_{t-1})]=(1+\beta^2)\delta^2$

But I don't understand why it's equal to $(1+\beta^2)\delta^2$

Comment: I think this should be in the Stat's stack exchange.

Comment: @Justin No. Fully on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out $\varepsilon$'s should be iid and follow
$$
\varepsilon_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\delta^2)
$$
(I am assuming giving the form)
$$
\mathbb{E}[(\varepsilon_t+\beta\varepsilon_{t-1})^2] = \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t^2+2\beta\varepsilon_t\varepsilon_{t-1} + \beta^2\varepsilon_{t-1}^2] = \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t^2] + 2\beta\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t\varepsilon_{t-1}] + \beta^2\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_{t-1}^2]
$$
In theory you should have
$$
\mathbb{V}[\varepsilon_t] = \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t^2] - \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t] = \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t^2] = \delta^2
$$
and since they should be independent 
$$
\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t\varepsilon_{t-1}] = \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t]\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_{t-1}] = 0
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{E}[(\varepsilon_t+\beta\varepsilon_{t-1})^2] = \delta^2 + 0 + \beta^2\delta^2 = (1+\beta^2)\delta^2
$$